# Accents of characters in Downton Abbey

Tags: dialects, accent, insular-english

To continue the question started in [identifying accents of British actors](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/identifying-accents-of-british-actors), there is one popular current cultural artifact with an excess of non-standard British accents, and that is The BBC series Downton Abbey.

For one very specific example, Anna Smith pronounces the word 'money' not as in standard English 'MUH-nee' (IPS /'mʌ nij/) but instead says something like 'moo-NAY' (IPA /mʊ 'ne/).

'Upstairs' I figure the accents are entirely RP except for Lady Grantham (with the [well discussed General American/RP mix](https://www.google.com/search?q=glady+grantham%27s+accent)).

But I'd very much like to know what each of the 'downstairs' characters' accents are.

A google search says nothing more than [what the IMDb FAQ about the show says](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606375/faq?ref_=tt_faq_sm#.2.1.8):

> Some of the servants (eg Mr Carson, Mrs Patmore, Anna and Sarah O'Brien) speak with northern accents (either Yorkshire or Lancashire).

And there is dialog and/or plot that identifies Branson as Irish and John Bates as Scottish.

What I'm looking for is something more definitive.

So, excluding the upstairs characters, what are the regions/accents of the following? (if possible please be specific, that is if you can tell the difference between, say, Mancunian and Yorkshire).

(for identities, consult [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606375/) )

- Charles Carson - butler
- John Bates - the earl's valet
- Sarah O'Brien - the countess's maid
- Anna Smith - Lady Mary's maid
- Thomas Barrow - footman
- Mrs. Hughes - housekeeper
- Daisy Mason - cook's aid
- Mrs. Patmore - cook
- Tom Branson - chauffeur
- Joseph Molesley - footman
- Dr. Clarkson - physician
- Ethel Parks - maid
- William Mason - footman

A simplified answer is sufficient. If all are Yorkshire (whatever that is) except for Branson and Bates, then I'd like that confirmed. But if more can be said then so much the better. (e.g. Dr. Clarkson sounds 'different' to me, but I just can't tell.)

Comment: I've heard the Yorkshire accent to be referred to as [tyke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyke_(dialect)). No idea why though.

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. Few if any of the cast speak in their "natural" accents, but those will normally influence their delivery. Also bear in mind they'd be attempting to reproduce accents from a century ago. It's unlikely any of them are truly "authentic", nor would that be a particular goal for either the cast or the production crew.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it is “Too Localized” once we’re down to debating which side of Sheffield somebody is from — which we quickly would be. :)

Comment: @tchrist: is there anything you can suggest that would render some modification of this to be reopenable?

Comment: @Mitch: To quote [John Lawler's comment here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80200/2637) *There's far more phonetic variation in any hundred mile square of Great Britain than there is in all of North America.* But to paraphrase tchrist, ELU can't be doing with guessing who was raised on the sunny side of the Pennines a century ago, as interpreted by TV production crews and cast members seeking ratings rather than historical linguistic accuracy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think I'm asking that. Alli want is for people to listen to how the individuals speak and figure as well as they can what accent it sounds like.

Comment: You can consider asking this on moviesSE (which also accepts questions on TV shows). While I don't think that this is expressly off topic or too localised, I reckon that it's a overbroad and time-consuming. It would make for a good blog post :)

Comment: Related? http://english.stackexchange.com/q/105682/14666

Comment: Though the question *has to do with* dialect, it is not a request to *explain anything* about dialect. It's a trivia question about a TV show, interesting but out of scope here. But you are welcome to recast as a request to explain something about dialect, if appropriate.

Comment: [Here is a meta thread](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/accent-identification-questions#comment11863_3786) about the appropriateness of this question and its ilk.

Comment: Partially covered [here](http://dialectblog.com/2012/01/19/accents-in-downton-abbey/).

Comment: @coleopterist: yes, that was one of my references (pardon the ommission). And it addresses upstairs, dismissing downstairs with the ubiquitous "the servants (who mostly speak with local Yorkshire accents)"; the '_mostly_' is exactly what I'm trying to elucidate. Who is left out of 'mostly'? Can anything more accurate be stated?

Comment: @terdon: True. I can't find an authority to back me up, but I believe when the first Lancastrian coalminers asked where they could pile up their slag-heaps, they were told to *"Stick it where the sun don't shine"*. Over the centuries it gradually built up to form the Pennines as we know them today. Only joking - I have a sister in Skipton, and she's always enthusing about the landscape, country walks, etc., right on her doorstep.

Comment: I think the accents upstairs are anachronistic. Someone like Lord Grantham in 1920 would have spoken with a far more differentiated RP. His is almost 21st century.

Comment: Just for the record, Downton Abbey is an ITV production, and has nothing to do with the BBC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Charles Carson - butler: **Yorkshire** ([ref](http://dialectblog.com/2012/01/19/accents-in-downton-abbey/#comment-10539))
- John Bates - the earl's valet
- Sarah O'Brien - the countess's maid
- Anna Smith - Lady Mary's maid
- Thomas Barrow - footman: **Mancunian** ([ref](http://downtonabbey-revisited.net/topic/36-the-dialect-of-the-servants/?p=304))
- Mrs. Hughes - housekeeper: **West Scots** ([ref 1](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/DowntonAbbey?from=Main.DowntonAbbey), [ref 2](http://dialectblog.com/2012/01/19/accents-in-downton-abbey/#comment-10539))
- Daisy Mason - cook's aid
- Mrs. Patmore - cook: **Mancunian** ([ref](http://downtonabbey-revisited.net/topic/36-the-dialect-of-the-servants/?p=304))
- Tom Branson - chauffeur
- Joseph Molesley - footman
- Dr. Clarkson - physician
- Ethel Parks - maid
- William Mason - footman: **Yorkshire** ([ref](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/DowntonAbbey?from=Main.DowntonAbbey))

Comment: Here's an attempt to answer the question based on references (some possibly of questionable reliability) around the web. I've marked it as a _community wiki_ in the hope that others will also chip in.

Comment: Sophie McShera who plays Daisy is from Bradford, West Yorkshire. Joanne Froggatt who plays Anna is from Littlebeck, North Yorkshire. It shouldn't be too hard to find interviews with them to check if they act with their normal accents (and to do the same with the others).

Comment: Tom Branson is Irish, as is the actor who plays him. I read that the character was originally meant to be a local, but it was decided to write the actor's nationality into the story rather than require him to put on a northern English accent.

Answer (score 1):

Miss O'Brien regularly speaks in a gently scouse accent from the Liverpool area, West Midlands. This would also be consistent with her Irish surname.

Comment: Liverpool, West Midlands?! That's like saying Chicago, New England.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Daisy's accent is from Bradford. Watched an accent tag of someone from Bradford and they sound really similar! And I remembered when Daisy says: "daredn't" instead of "dare not" in the first episode and I found [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4ceIMKZVzwcC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=i+daredn%27t+accent&source=bl&ots=6aqPFuoFIR&sig=quSM8eiseRYHVXF_lGXS-BgzsPg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Xr9rUYunLaLJ0AWo3oAI&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=i%20daredn%27t%20accent&f=false).