# Why is the Yorkshire dialect called 'Tyke'?

Tags: british-english, dialects, accent

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyke_%28dialect%29):

> The Yorkshire dialect refers to the varieties of English used in the Northern England historic county of Yorkshire. Those varieties are often referred to as Broad Yorkshire or **Tyke**.

Why is the Yorkshire dialect called 'Tyke'? Can the accent be referred to as *tyke* as well?

ODO's [definition of tyke](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tyke) includes a number of negative senses. Is *this* sense also derogatory?

Comment: Thank you for this question. In Nick Park's animated short film, The Wrong Trousers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrong_trousers), Wallace tells the thieving penguin, "I'll get you for this, you tyke." Nick Park coming from Lancashire, would this be an insult?

Comment: Racist in the extreme. What an insult to the penguin.

Comment: Look at the origin, from Norse tìk = bitch.  Not sure if that's pejorative or a female dog.

Answer (score 7):

As OED says, *tyke* originally came from Old Norse ***tík*** - female dog, bitch. It's not exclusively reserved for Geordies (or people from Newcastle), but as OED also points out, it often does have that sense - *"perhaps originally opprobrious; but now accepted and owned [by them]"*.

I recall that my grandmother, who never lived anywhere but Sussex for all her 99 years, used to sometimes call me a *dirty little tyke*. I doubt all ["Novocastrians"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Novocastrian%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are happy to be thus called.

---

FWIW here's the full relevant OED entry...

> **3.** A nickname for a Yorkshireman: in full *Yorkshire tyke.*
>    (Perhaps originally opprobrious; but now accepted and owned.
>    It may have arisen from the fact that in Yorkshire tyke is in common use for dog.)

...but no mention of the word being used to mean the Yorkshire accent/dialect.

Comment: Thank you. Do people commonly call the Yorkshire dialect/accent _tyke_? I'd also appreciate it if you could include the OED entry (for this sense) in full.

Comment: @coleopterist: To be honest, until I read [your comment on this earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105536/accents-of-characters-in-downton-abbey), I doubt I've *ever* heard "tyke" used on its own to mean the dialect itself. Yorkshire is a *huge* county - but it doesn't even reach as far as Newcastle, even though they're sometimes called tykes too. Bearing in mind people from the whole general area have a reputation for being quick to take offence, *and* handy with their fists, I would strongly advise *not* calling one a "tyke" to his face, whatever OED may say.

Comment: Considering my own grandmother said the same, I’d say *tyke* is a common word for such little buggers as thee and me. And we haven’t seen the ancestral homelands of Hertforshire for many centuries now.

Comment: As someone from Yorkshire I can tell you that I've never heard the Yorkshire dialect called 'Tyke'. The word is usually aimed at a child or dog who is cheeky or mischievous; a 'dirty little tyke' would imply they had come home with muddy clothes or feet, from playing outside all day and probably getting up to mischief. It could be used affectionately or pejoratively. In my experience it's unlikely to be aimed at an adult, but maybe it is in some parts of Yorkshire. I don't think the penguin counts as an adult, Wallace calls him a tyke precisely because he's not a human adult.

Comment: @Mynamite: But I take it you do realise that *some* Brits (particularly those bloody Lancastrians, who've never much liked Geordies anyway) sometimes use Tyke as a [facetious] perjorative for Yorkshiremen and/or those from Tyneside. Not me though (I just call you all "bloody northerners"! :)

Comment: @coleopterist: I've added the relevant OED entry. I reckon whoever wrote that Wikipedia entry read too much into a magazine column jokingly called [Does Tha Speak Tyke](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/mbarts/html/NF2234234?thread=4447752) in the county magazine [The Dalesman](http://www.dalesman.co.uk/). Which I suspect is more a bit of fun than anything else.

Comment: Thank you. I remember some British comedians use it occasionally (although I'm a li'l fuzzy on whether they were referring to the dialect). _[How to talk Tyke](http://books.google.com/books?id=S7odAQAAIAAJ)_ is a book on the subject; while it may appear humorous in nature, [there are other examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=tyke+yorkshire+dialect&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks) which use the term and are not. For example, "Former miners work as guides, and explain the details – sometimes with a suitably authentic and almost impenetrable mix of local dialect (known in Yorkshire as Tyke) ...".

Comment: Interesting. You'd know better than I what she meant, but I know in the USA "little tyke" is often used to mean "small child" (devoid of any sociolinguistic meaning at all). In fact, there's a big [toy company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Tikes) by that name.

Comment: I always laugh when you Brits describe a place in England as huge!  What you call an all-day excursion, most Americans would drive just to get a taco!  And, no less of an authority than Bill Bryson said so!

Answer (score 0):

Im Yorkshire born and bred, the term tyke used to describe a yorkshire born and bred person is due to this :- Yorkshire people are called tykes to mean they are clever and skilled at the occupation or hobby they have adopted and also have a hint of cunning and mischief. The name tykes originally meant extremely active and quick-thinking dogs.

Comment: I find your last sentence the most interesting. Given FF's reference that the word was Old English for female dog, one could see where it might have transformed into "active and quick-thinking" ones (if female dogs got that rep for some reason). From there, the transformation to particularly energetic young children isn't too tough to picture.

Answer (score -3):

I have a feeling that a Yorkshirewman  or woman usseing the word tyke . is rfering to someanother town or city inside yourkshire. im from east yourks and never realyheard the term Tyke,so much,mabe about  leeds or even york.

Comment: While similar answers may be useful, this one is unlikely to help future readers because it is so hard to read. This can often be avoided by using spell check and grammar check before posting.