# In which accent does Lieutenant Aldo Raine (Brad Pitt) speak?

Tags: speech, accent, cinema

I don't know if Stack Exchange is the right place to ask this question but I am very keen to find out:

Which accent has Brad Pitt adopted in the movie *Inglourious Basterds* for the role of Lieutenant Aldo Raine?

Comment: [A question about the accents of *Downton Abbey* characters](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105536/accents-of-characters-in-downton-abbey) was recently closed as "too localized".  This question may meet the same fate.  On the other hand, the *Downton Abbey* question had a +7 score, so apparently there was some interest.  Maybe a meta thread is in order on questions like this.

Comment: I started [a meta thread](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/accent-identification-questions).

Comment: [I think](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3788/18696) that questions about *actors' portrayals* of accents are off-topic (that is, out of scope). Even the [current] single answer to this question cannot be certain.

Comment: Tough call. Why don't you ask "Brad Pitt's accent in Inglorious Bastards". It has its own [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Brad-Pitts-accent-in-Inglorious-Bastards/323357699669) page.

Answer (score 9):

The character [Aldo Raine is from *Maynardville, Tennessee*](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0106963/quotes) and is a [hillbilly](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hillbilly) who enjoys bootlegging [moonshine](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moonshine?q=moonshine). While I'm unsure about the accuracy of Pitt's accent for the time period, it certainly sounds (possibly intentionally) overdone to my ears.

Answer (score 7):

Having grown up in east Tennessee, I can confirm that his accent is consistent with the older generation of locals from the deep mountains.  It is likely that Brad Pitt spent some time in the area and adopted the thickest accent he could muster of those he heard in the region.

Answer (score 7):

I grew up in Tennessee and live very close to Maynardville. Pitt's accent is the closest I've heard from a non-native. He would pass for a local. It's that good.

Answer (score 4):

His accent is consistant with the dialect spoken by natives of the Appalachian Region of the U.S. Commonly spoken by individuals from  NW Georgia, W NC/SC, VA, E TN, & SE KY.
JDnTN I'm with you 100% it is a pretty authentic accent, my granddad, & all of his brothers sound much like Raine,& Use similar wording/idioms. I'm from NC btw.  My question is was Aldo Raine based on SGT. John Fulcher? A man who also 
spoke with a similar accent, and led a sniper squad of all native Americans who scalped their Nazi Victims, & utilized guerrilla warfare tactics.

Answer (score 1):

As stated earlier, the accuracy of the accent for the time period is uncertain, but in the movie his character even says he's from the Smokey mountains and that his father was a mountain man. So you could further research accents from that region